# Button at viewForHeaderInSection method code errors

Tags: ios

In my code there is a button at the `viewForHeaderInSection` method. The button action is following:

```
[bt addTarget:self action:@selector(addCell:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

The method launched from that button is following:

```
- (void)addCell:(UIButton *)bt{

    // If section of more information
    if(bt.tag == 2) {

        // Initially more info is close, if more info is open
        if(ifOpen) { //**error here (use of undeclared identifier fOpen)
            DLog(@"close More info");

            // Set height of section
            heightOfSection = 0.0f; //**error here (use of undeclared identifier heightOfSection)

            // Reset the parameter that more info is closed now
            ifOpen = NO;//**error here (use of undeclared identifier fOpen)
        }else {
            // Set height of section
            heightOfSection = 45.0f;//**error here (use of undeclared identifier heightOfSection)
            // Reset the parameter that more info is closed now
            DLog(@"open more info again");
            ifOpen = YES;//**error here (use of undeclared identifier fOpen)
        }
        //[self.tableView reloadData];
        [self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:2] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }

}// end addCell
```

I am getting error warnings at the lines marked with //**error here.
You are kindly requested to help me cleaning this piece of code. Thank you.

Comment: Those are probably instance variables you didn't add when you copied the code. Don't just blindly copy and paste code. You must understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is `ifOpen` declared anywhere? if not the compile is quite right when it complains about ifOpen not being declared.

Comment: Thank you @rist, I guess this is not declared anywhere. I have taken this code from a tutorial, and how could I substitute heightOfSection for the real height of the table section?